# InDesign: how to save PDF file

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, file-format

I need to save a PDF from InDesign, but can't seem to have the option when I go to "Save as", any ideas? I've done it with Photoshop/Illustrator, but have never used InDesign before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`File > Export` and Choose PDF.

Unlike Photoshop and Illustrator, InDesign doesn't "save as" to PDFs. You must *export* to PDF with InDesign.